# GIFV not loading in local HTML page

Tags: html, gif, animated-gif

I have a simple html file that consists of a gifv video which does not play on Google Chrome while if I enter the code at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro), it renders properly which makes me confused.

I have checked the other previous solutions to fix the gifv problem but it is still not rendering on my html file.

HTML script

```
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="91S22q6" data-context="false"><a href="//imgur.com/91S22q6">
View post on imgur.com</a>
</blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example that illustrates the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you- gifvs will not load locally when using imgur's embed code. After a lot of head scratching I figured out that if you load your html file over a python server, the gifs will render. It's really easy to do, it's just a one line command. Here's an article explaining how to do it:

http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/how-to-use-simplehttpserver/

here's the basic summary:

"An advantage with the built-in HTTP server is that you don't have to install
and configure anything. The only thing that you need, is to have Python installed.

That makes it perfect to use when you need a quick web server running and you
don't want to mess with setting up apache.

You can use this to turn any directory in your system into your web server
directory.

To start a HTTP server on port 8000 (which is the default port), simple type:

python -m SimpleHTTPServer [port]"

Answer (score 0):

http://s.imgur.com/min/embed-controller.js refers to `window.location.protocol`.  If you are browsing a resource served from `file://`, this is going to break the expectations of that script.

That means you need to serve this via `http://` or `https://` to work.